# Find the version of an ActiveX COM component

Tags: javascript, com, activex

I have a web application that uses an ActiveX COM component, for example:

```
<OBJECT id="SomeObject" style="VISIBILITY: hidden" etc...
    classid="clsid:0A6AD658-F144-4412-AB94-9C8F298973E1"></OBJECT>
```

I've produced the ActiveX control myself, and I want to be able to determine in JavaScript the version of the control that is installed and being used on the page.

I thought I could expose a method on the object than exposed the version number somehow, for example:

```
<script language="JavaScript>
    var version = SomeObject.GetVersion();
</script>
```

But that seemed really messy. I wondered if there was a built in COM / ActiveX mechanism for finding version numbers - whats the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the [ActiveX specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972(VS.85).aspx) that has the construct of *version*, you can browse around and see that many ActiveX controls have Version property.
You can improve the code (a little) by providing a Version property instead of a method.

You can also provide a [version in the codebase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533576(VS.85).aspx) and know that you have at least the version ask for.